# EmptyPage Error in Django pagination

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pagination, django-pagination

I am tring to make digg-style pagination in my django application. I used custom templatetags. First and last pages didnt work and I dont understand how to fix that. However other pages work fine. Where I did mistake?

**First page Error:** EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 20, in project_list
    return render(request, 'project/project_list.html', {'projects': projects, 'paginator': paginator})
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 225, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\templatetags\pagination.py", line 48, in custom_paginator
    'previous': page_obj.previous_page_number(),
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 136, in previous_page_number
    return self.paginator.validate_number(self.number - 1)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 38, in validate_number
    raise EmptyPage('That page number is less than 1')
django.core.paginator.EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1
```

**Last page Error:**  EmptyPage That page contains no results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 20, in project_list
    return render(request, 'project/project_list.html', {'projects': projects, 'paginator': paginator})
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 225, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\templatetags\pagination.py", line 48, in custom_paginator
    'previous': page_obj.previous_page_number(),
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 136, in previous_page_number
    return self.paginator.validate_number(self.number - 1)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 38, in validate_number
    raise EmptyPage('That page number is less than 1')
django.core.paginator.EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1
[04/Mar/2017 19:13:59] "GET /ru/account/dashboard/project/list/?page=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 152849
Internal Server Error: /ru/account/dashboard/project/list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 20, in project_list
    return render(request, 'project/project_list.html', {'projects': projects, 'paginator': paginator})
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 225, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\templatetags\pagination.py", line 49, in custom_paginator
    'next': page_obj.next_page_number(),
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 133, in next_page_number
    return self.paginator.validate_number(self.number + 1)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 43, in validate_number
    raise EmptyPage('That page contains no results')
django.core.paginator.EmptyPage: That page contains no results
[04/Mar/2017 19:16:12] "GET /ru/account/dashboard/project/list/?page=12 HTTP/1.1" 500 152777
```

**views.py**

```
def project_list(request):
    objects = Project.objects.filter(status='public', membership__user=request.user)
    paginator = Paginator(objects, 1)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        projects = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        projects = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        projects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'project/project_list.html', {'projects': projects, 'paginator': paginator})
```

**pagination.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

LEADING_PAGE_RANGE_DISPLAYED = TRAILING_PAGE_RANGE_DISPLAYED = 5
LEADING_PAGE_RANGE = TRAILING_PAGE_RANGE = 4
NUM_PAGES_OUTSIDE_RANGE = 2
ADJACENT_PAGES = 2


def custom_paginator(context):
    paginator = context['paginator']
    page_obj = context['projects']
    pages = paginator.num_pages
    page = page_obj.number
    in_leading_range = in_trailing_range = False
    pages_outside_leading_range = pages_outside_trailing_range = range(0)
    if pages <= LEADING_PAGE_RANGE_DISPLAYED + NUM_PAGES_OUTSIDE_RANGE + 1:
        in_leading_range = in_trailing_range = True
        page_range = [n for n in range(1, pages + 1)]
    elif page <= LEADING_PAGE_RANGE:
        in_leading_range = True
        page_range = [n for n in range(1, LEADING_PAGE_RANGE_DISPLAYED + 1)]
        pages_outside_leading_range = [n + pages for n in range(0, -NUM_PAGES_OUTSIDE_RANGE, -1)]
    elif page > pages - TRAILING_PAGE_RANGE:
        in_trailing_range = True
        page_range = [n for n in range(pages - TRAILING_PAGE_RANGE_DISPLAYED + 1, pages + 1) if 0 < n <= pages]
        pages_outside_trailing_range = [n + 1 for n in range(0, NUM_PAGES_OUTSIDE_RANGE)]
    else:
        page_range = [n for n in range(page - ADJACENT_PAGES, page + ADJACENT_PAGES + 1) if 0 < n <= pages]
        pages_outside_leading_range = [n + pages for n in range(0, -NUM_PAGES_OUTSIDE_RANGE, -1)]
        pages_outside_trailing_range = [n + 1 for n in range(0, NUM_PAGES_OUTSIDE_RANGE)]

    request = context['request']
    params = request.GET.copy()
    if 'page' in params:
        del (params['page'])
    get_params = params.urlencode()

    return {
        'pages': pages,
        'page': page,
        'previous': page_obj.previous_page_number(),
        'next': page_obj.next_page_number(),
        'has_previous': page_obj.has_previous(),
        'has_next': page_obj.has_next(),
        'page_range': page_range,
        'in_leading_range': in_leading_range,
        'in_trailing_range': in_trailing_range,
        'pages_outside_leading_range': pages_outside_leading_range,
        'pages_outside_trailing_range': pages_outside_trailing_range,
        'get_params': get_params,
    }


register.inclusion_tag("project/pagination.html", takes_context=True)(custom_paginator)
```

**project_list.html**

```
{% for project in projects %}
   *** LIST OF PROJECTS HERE ***
{% endfor %}
{% custom_paginator %}
```

**pagination.html**

```
{% spaceless %}
  {% if has_previous %}
    <li><a href="{% if get_params %}?{{ get_params }}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ previous }}">&laquo; Prev</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if not in_leading_range %}
    {% for p in pages_outside_trailing_range %}
      <li><a href="{% if get_params %}?{{ get_params }}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ p }}">{{ p }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li><span class="ellipsis">...</span></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for p in page_range %}
    {% if p == page %}
      <li><span class="active">{{ p }}</span></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{% if get_params %}?{{ get_params }}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ p }}">{{ p }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if not in_trailing_range %}
    <li><span class="ellipsis">...</span></li>
    {% for p in pages_outside_leading_range reversed %}
      <li><a href="{% if get_params %}?{{ get_params }}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ p }}">{{ p }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if has_next %}
    <li><a href="{% if get_params %}?{{ get_params }}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ next }}">Next &raquo;</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: What is that custom_paginator template tag for, and where are you using it? Also you need to show us the full tracebacks, not just the last few lines.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I update my post with full traceback and  custom_paginator i use in my project_list.html file. Do you have any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

The tracebacks show that the error is occurring in your template tag. You call `previous_page_number` and `next_page_number` without checking whether `has_previous` and `has_next` return True.

But I can't really see why you would do any of that; better to pass `page_obj` and call the methods directly in the template.

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
  <li><a href="{% if get_params %}?{{ get_params }}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo; Prev</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

etc.